# symfony doctrine one-to-many entity setup

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I'm trying to get my head around the entity annotations for a doctrine one to many relationship.

For example, if table_one (T1) is:

```
email_address (string)
```

and table_two (T2) is

```
userid_email (string)
entry (int)
```

(email_address.table_one = userid_email.table_two) and there are multiple entries in table_two i.e

```
 userid_email=test@email.com,entry=5;
 userid_email=test@email.com,entry=6
```

Do I create the annotation for the T1 Entity

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="T1")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="table_two",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="userid", referencedColumnName="userid_email")}
 *      )
 */
protected entries;
public function __construct()
{
    $this->entries = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

And then in a createQuery I query on T1 :

```
 $query = $em->createQuery('
    SELECT u.email, u.entries
    FROM AppBundle:T1 u 
    WHERE u.email = :an_email_address');
```

For the above query I would always get this error :

Error: Invalid PathExpression. Must be a StateFieldPathExpression

Is there something I am setting up improperly for the relationship?

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration seems to be wrong, try something like:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="T1")
 * @ORM\joinColumn={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="userid", referencedColumnName="userid_email")}
 *      )
 */
```